# Global filters nots using FilterProviders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've used Brad Wilson's 'UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider' as described here... http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt4-filters.html

The trouble is that it only seems to work when the filter is *not* assigned as a global filter. Do the global filters not use filter providers?

Cheers, Ian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the post:

> At this point in time, there is no way to register a global filter with the service locator.

You are manually providing an instance of the global filter when registering it so there is no DI into them.